# Android Studio shows "Installing APKs..." with an "s". Why multiple APKs?

Tags: android, apk

In Android Studio, while deploying an app using USB debugging it shows "Installing APKs" with an "s". What's the backstory for the multiple apks? Probably the slices.apks have something to do with this but what's the whole story?

Comment: Just in case you deploy more than one apk at the same time. Google should correct this.

Comment: So it does mean that there is no significant meaning of it, because we usually never install multiple apks at the same time and even so, every studio's window bear a single project at a time.